# activatedRoute.url subscription not receiving events when changing routing for other outlet

Tags: angular

When i am on the url: http://localhost:2201/dash-board and navigate by `router.navigate` to the same url but different named outlet like:

http://localhost:2201/dash-board/(named-outlet:page1)

the following subscription not getting the change from the activeRouter:

```
this.activatedRoute.url.switchMap(x => x).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Can someone share with me what can be the problem? I know I can use `this.router.events` but I still want to understand why my way is not working.

Comment: have you tried using `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url` ?

Comment: Where is this code? If you are navigating to different named router outlets, aren't you navigating to different components?

Comment: You can not subscribe to snapshoot...